# How run in same port Angular and Node.JS Express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular5

This is might be possible to duplicate question but not able to understand how to configure FE and BE together run them both.

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39845526) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46782456) questions, but couldn't understand.

My Node+Express running on 4300

```
app.post('/postData', function(req, res) {
//some worst logics here :)
});
```

And

Angular 5 running on 4200. Below is my FE service that calling post endpoint

```
postData(feData) {
        console.log(feData);
        this.http.post('/postData', feData, this.httpHeader).subscribe((data) => {
        });
    }
```

What I tried is opened two cmd Windows: one to run `server.js` by `node server.js` and another one with ng serve.

Result:

> ```
> 404 not fount(cannot post)
> ```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Why not just add `'localhost:4300/postData'` to your http call?

Comment: You can't host server-side code on Github Pages. It's for static sites only: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/

Comment: @Shadowlauch just now only i tried as you said.. am failed again . 404 not found

Comment: thank you @Brandon am really not aware about that

Comment: You're welcome. I work a lot with Node and Angular, and host my sites on Heroku. It's inexpensive and couldn't be easier to set up. I keep the Angular and Node apps on separate dynos rather than try to run them in the same process.

Comment: at least ll be happy if my app running locally. could you pls tell me how to run them perfecly

Comment: I always keep the front and back-end code as separate applications. It's simpler and faster. I would recommend using Nest.js: https://nestjs.com/ so you can work with TypeScript on both sides. Nest's design is very similar to Angular's modules, so there's less context switching.

Comment: I have deployed two applications built with Nest, both with Angular 5+ front-ends to Heroku with no issues. Why do you feel you need the app(s) running on the same port?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need to do on this case is move your Angular 5 application to run under express process. You can achieve this following this [tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example) - See item 2

I removed some complications but I really recommend you to take a look on the tutorial.

```
npm install --save express body-parser
```

Create a file to run your node app like `server.js` and add following code:

```
var app = require('app.js');
var debug = require('debug')('mean-app:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '4300');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  debug('Listening on ' + port);
}
```

Edit "package.json" to specify how you app will start:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng build && node server.js",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Now, create app.js which will run express:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var sample = require('./routes/sample.js');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'false'}));

//Put your angular dist folder here
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/samples', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use('/sample', sample);

module.exports = app;
```

It's a good practice to create routes folder for your elements. Create a file `routes/sample.js` with following content:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('RESTful API');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Run the server using node command:

```
npm start
```

Comment: after following up your above config. now am able reach my api successfully ... the mistake what made is that i have not setup common router. thanks alot

Comment: Is putting angular in the dist folder what makes it run in the same port with express?

Comment: Yes. Express will serve a plain html files on the folder where you apply 'express.static' function. It tells to serve those files as a static content. Once you copy your angular build result on this folder, it will serve them.

Comment: I was able to successfully run both API and website from the same server. But when the user refreshes any page from the browser, it takes them to the home page. What is want is when the user is on page https://myserver.com/books/434334 and when the user clicks the browser refresh button, then the page should stay in https://myserver.com/books/434334 and not https://myserver.com/books.

Comment: Is there a way to debug the express server and angular project at same time? I add some break points at angular component files, but always failed to trigger.

Answer (score 2):

By Experience, Keep the Backend or Microservices separate from your frontend applications.

Comment: to late for me, any solution? to run  angular front end and node services on the same  port

Comment: Please explain why! If your app is isolated, i.e. the API is closed to all domains except itself, then this architecture seems fine to me.